# How to keep multiple lists with different item lengths to have the same height

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to have multiple lists, side by side, and I want to achieve 2 goals:

1. is to sync the scroll between these lists, so when I m looking at a certain item from one list, to be able to easily check the same item from the other lists, but this is fairly easy to achieve if I get point 2 to work.
2. is to make sure that a certain row from the lists have the same height, for example:
   second element in all lists is a phrase, in the first list the phrase fits in one row, in the second list the phrase fits in 3 rows, the goal is to be sure that even though on the first list the phrase would fit in one row, to make the space for that item 3 rows tall, so that is easy to implement sync scrolling and to check other values.

My lists are simple components like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>
    Conflicted Version Item
  </h3>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
  <h6>Bla bla bla</h6>
</div>

//css

.container{
  max-width: 25vw;
  min-width: 18vw;
  padding: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 90%;
}
```

width the list container looking like:

```
<div class="conflicted-versions">
    <app-conflicted-version-item></app-conflicted-version-item>
    <app-conflicted-version-item></app-conflicted-version-item>
    <app-conflicted-version-item></app-conflicted-version-item>
    ...
  </div>

//css
.conflicted-versions{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 30vh;
  }
```

With the remark that app-conflicted-version-item is the list described in the first code snippet.

I would love some suggestions to solve the second issue, because I m fairly comfortable to do the first on myself if I get the second one right.

Comment: How are you populating these lists? Is there some kind of array maping?

Comment: @HelenaSánchez the lists will be dinamically populated with different fields, but all of them will get the same fields, because the fields in the lists describe some objects, the objects can be stored in an array I guess, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that's what I imagined. If you know the fields beforehand, it may be easier to build the lists row by row, instead of by columns. I'll post a detailed answer so you see what I'm referring to

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it like this:

```html
<Row>*
  <Col class="list">
  <Col class="list">
</Row>
```

You could do:

```html
<Col class="mega-list">
  <Row class="field1">
    <Col>list1.field1</Col>
    <Col>list2.field1</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row class="field2">
    <Col>list1.field2</Col>
    <Col>list2.field2</Col>
  </Row>
</Col>
```

This way, the rows would always fit the max-height needed for the longest content.

*(The Rows and Cols could just be divs with `flex-direction: row` or `column`, respectively)